# Can a LoRa signal pass through human bodies?

Tags: wireless, data

If I want to transfer a packet of data from one LoRa to another up to 1km away, if there's a crowd of people will the signal not get through?

If so is there an alternative to LoRa to transfer packets of data without and broadband cellular networks or wifi or Bluetooth (as it won't reach 1km) or can I change the frequency to pass through human bodies but still reach 1km distance?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Humans do absorb RF, but the amount of attenuation caused by human bodies is less at lower frequencies. According to [an abstract for a journal article](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/3696080), at 85 MHz:

> ...the local specific absorption rate (SAR) was found to be approximately equal to 0.05 W/kg...

According to Wikipedia, LoRa uses the following frequency bands:

> ...169 MHz, 433 MHz, 868 MHz (Europe) and 915 MHz (North America).

This suggests that LoRa transmissions would be attenuated by human bodies. When evaluating an actual implementation, it won't be enough to estimate the intermediate mass of human bodies and then calculate the attenuation, because there will be many other potential factors in signal propagation, such as re-radiation by conducting objects in the space in question.

Answer (score 1):

LoRa is RF radio technology and the crowd does not affect on it.

Comment: So if I have 2 Lora RA-02 modules when Im trying to send data it'll send like

LoraTransmitter --> Radio Tower ----> LoraReceiver

Comment: i didn't tried. but i think it is possible to connect two RA-02 without center radio tower. see this tutorial. https://www.smart-prototyping.com/blog/Sending-and-Receiving-Weather-Data-with-a-LoRa-Module

Comment: So two RA-02 would be able to transmit and recieve within a 1km radius even with a crowd of people in between??

Comment: as I said, I think it is possible.